# Powering off sends me to "Launch Windows Repair" automatically instead! What do I do?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

With Windows 2008 R2 Server, I noticed that if I remotely reboot the machine (because it is hung or I think it is hung), the server, when it restarts, defaults to "Launch Windows Repair" (or something similar) rather than "Start Windows Normally".

To change it, I have to trek down to the server room and change the boot up otherwise it will go into an endless loop (because I don't have the setup media and DVD-ROM installed).

This seems to be new with 2008 R2 because I have not seen it elsewhere.

What do I do? How can I remove this or change the default?

Comment: I've seen this on occasion too but not frequently enough for me to worry about it.  I suspect it's part of the NTFS autorepair as I've only seen it when I've pulled the plug rather than actually shutting down the system.  Can you tell how you are rebooting the system?

Comment: Pulling the plug yes, with a remote PDU switch. It makes the remote PDU switch completely useless if I need to be physically in front of the computer in order to boot it back up. I have not seen this behavior in Win2008 (only R2) or earlier... it seems like a regression to me.

Comment: ... and I want to change the default so that I can fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I would investigate why it's hanging (or you think it's hung), rather than turning off the option to "launch windows repair"...

Based on your additional info, you could try reagentc /disable from an elevated command line.  It sounds as if it's entering the [Windows Recovery Environment](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/high-availability.aspx).

Comment: Yes, of course I am, but the server may reboot and it should handle a power outage without requiring user intervention to start it back up.

Comment: so you negged me for not assuming that you were investigating this?  At any rate, your question did not indicate that.  And your server SHOULD shutdown gracefully during a power outage because it's on a UPS.

Comment: What I'm getting at is that on a server specifically, seeing that "Launch Windows Repair" screen should be a rare occasion.